# Lax or lenient?

Tags: differences

I was wondering whether there is a significant difference between the two words 'lax' & 'lenient'. 
I was looking at the sentence: "He was pretty lenient in his punishment of us". I felt that 'lenient' could be switched out for 'lax', but my textbook tells me that is not correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: `Lax` has more senses than `lenient`. It's often used to mean careless or negligent. That being said; I don't see why you can't use lax in the sentence given.

Comment: "Lax" implies careless neglect.  "Lenient" implies conscious "going easy on you".  The difference is primarily in the degree to which the low severity of the punishment or whatever was unplanned vs intended.

Comment: @tusharRaj Neither of webster or the oxford dictionaries understand lax as a synonym for lenient. Both give the cruicial distinction of "enough", as in "not strict enough" whereas lenient is "not strict". So the exchange of lax for lenient will change the meaning of the sntence, for many(most) people.

Comment: @DRF: Umm actually, [Oxford does](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/lax). Look carefully.

Comment: @tusharRaj Ahh good point. I think I misstated what I tried to claim. That being that the definitions don't offer synonymity but you are correct that oxford does have lenient as a synonym of lax. Though surprisingly webster doesn't even have it in related words, its understanding of lax is much closer to mine having a strong negative connotation.

Comment: Thanks everybody. :)
So what I take away from your comments is the following: lax has a much more negative connotation than lenient. A synonym for lax would be sloppy, rather than lenient. Lenient implies the person could've been much more strict but chose not to be. Lax implies that he should've been more strict, but didn't manage / didn't want to be. Any objections?

Comment: You've summarized it quite well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words definitely overlap in their meaning and use, but looking at the definitions, *[lenient](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lenient)* stays close to its primary application to **mild** punishment or discipline:

> adjective
>
> 1.0 (Of a punishment or person in authority) more merciful or tolerant than expected:
>   *in the view of the Court the sentence was too lenient
>
>   lenient magistrates*
>
> **Origin**
>
> Mid 17th century (in sense 2): from Latin lenient- 'soothing', from
>   the verb lenire, from lenis 'mild, gentle'.
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

On the other hand, *[lax](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lax)* denotes a more general description of **looseness** applied to a wider variety of conditions and activities--muscles, speech, [attention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20attention%2Clenient%20attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20attention%3B%2Cc0), [expectations](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20expectations%2Clenient%20expectations&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20expectations%3B%2Cc0), [discipline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20discipline%2Clenient%20discipline&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20discipline%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clenient%20discipline%3B%2Cc0), [morality](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20morality%2Clenient%20morality&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20morality%3B%2Cc0), etc.:

> adjective
>
> 1.0 Not sufficiently strict, severe, or careful:
>   *lax security arrangements at the airport
>
>   he’d been a bit lax about discipline in
>   school lately*
>
> 2.0 (Of the limbs or muscles) relaxed:
>   *muscles have more potential energy when they are stretched than when they are lax*
>
> 2.1 (Of the bowels) loose.
>
> 2.2 Phonetics (Of a speech sound, especially a vowel) pronounced with the vocal muscles relaxed. The opposite of tense.
>
> **Origin**
>
> Late Middle English (in the sense 'loose', said of the bowels): from
>   Latin laxus.
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

Specifically, *lenient* usually connotes the soft treatment institutions, groups or individuals extend **toward others**, while *lax* is just as likely to refer to their relaxed **general behavior**, as in *lax* [habits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20habits%2Clenient%20habits&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20habits%3B%2Cc0), [operation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20operation%2Clenient%20operation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20operation%3B%2Cc0) and [maintenance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20maintenance%2Clenient%20maintenance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20maintenance%3B%2Cc0), which are rarely, if ever, used with *lenient*.

Even where *lenient* and *lax* overlap in usage, *lax* tends to have a broader application. In the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lax%20procedures%2Clenient%20procedures&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clax%20procedures%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clenient%20procedures%3B%2Cc0), the expression *lax procedures* is about seven times more common than *lenient procedures*:

[image]

More importantly, exploring the underlying data shows that *lenient procedures* almost always refers to procedural interaction with an **outside entity**, as exemplified in "lenient procedures of the German denazification" described in *[Nazi Crimes against Jews and German Post-War Justice](https://books.google.com/books?id=dfzmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT74&dq=%22lenient%20procedures%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIh8nIvKngxgIVybgeCh0Ujg4K#v=onepage&q=%22lenient%20procedures%22&f=false)*, by Edith Raim:

> The results of this lackadaisical approach soon became obvious. “It was pointed out that through the lenient procedures of the German
>   denazification authorities and a consequent liberal employment policy
>   by the Minister of Justice, a large part of formerly removed Nazis had
>   been reinstated within the Württemberg-Baden justice system..."

In contrast, *lax procedures* are just as likely to refer to **internal dynamics** as external interactions, as seen in *[The Moral Responsibilities of Companies](https://books.google.com/books?id=JW6oBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT182&dq=%22lax+procedures%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAjgKahUKEwjNicCsrODGAhUMVh4KHWqaC9A#v=onepage&q=%22lax%20procedures%22&f=false)*, by Chris Chapple :

> The fine was, at least in part, intended to deter other banks from similarly lax procedures.

**Conclusion**

Although *lax* and *lenient* are synonyms that overlap in meaning and usage, the connotations of *lenient* focus more on **mild** punishment, discipline, and restrictions placed on outside parties. *Lax* generally describes a broader range of **loose** conditions and activities, and is not routinely limited to external interactions.